# Why was the cocoa touch main function template like this?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

With the dawn of ARC came a new main function template in xcode that makes a lot more sense.  However, I have a question about the old template.

As everyone knows, the old main function template in XCode for Cocoa touch applications was this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

However, the last two lines are unreachable because the docs clearly state that UIApplicationMain never returns.  It simply makes a call to exit() when it is done.  So why did Apple opt for a template like this?  Why not just this?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
}
```

Is it because people would take this as an example, and not release their autorelease pools properly?  Or because it would trip up the static analyzer?  Or something else possibly?

That question might be too open-ended so I will ask it another way.  Is there a technical reason for using the template the way that Apple did?

Comment: Just a thought: aren't you contradicting yourself when you say "UIApplicationMain never returns [a value]" and you suggest returning UIApplicationMain even though the main function requires an int to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great answer but if you actually try your example then you get an `Unused variable` warning, which would be a bit slack to give everyone a warning with a freshly created project.

Comment: Actually, this answer is fine!  "To prevent a compiler warning" is perfectly acceptable.  I will wait a bit to see if any others come in, but if not I will happily accept this one.